# Libgdx textures are all weird when opening app after the back button is pressed?

Tags: android, libgdx, scene2d

So this is my dilemma, I'm really close to publishing my game on the play store.

When testing my app on a device I realised that when the **home button** is clicked, and followed by opening the app again. Everything is handled fine.

However, when the **back button** is pressed and the app is opened up again, the textures in my game load up weird, like really weird.

Heres are the screen shots of what is supposed to look like and what its not supposed to..

Here is the link that shows what is supposed to look like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj8wr.jpg

And here's the one that loads up after the back button is pressed https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRML7.jpg

After testing this for quite some time, I believe the problem is that when the back button is clicked, it triggers a "quit" type function that is supposed to **EXIT** the app. However, the app for some reason still exist in the background of the phone which leads to the weird textures being loaded after the back button is clicked. If I am correct what do I need to do on my end to handle this type of behaviour.

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{
    private static final int FLOOR_Y_OFFSET = -150;
    private static final int FOREGROUND_Y_OFFSET = -150;

    private FishyDash game;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;

    private Texture background;
    private Texture foreground;
    private Vector2 foregroundPos1, foregroundPos2;
    private Texture floor;
    private Vector2 floorPos1, floorPos2;
    private Fish fishy;

    //TABLE STUFF
    private Table table;
    private Table buttonTable;
    private Stage stage;

    private Image game_title;
    private Skin skin;
    private TextureAtlas buttonAtlas;
    private TextButton buttonPlay, buttonRate;
    private Viewport gamePort;

    public BitmapFont font;

    //Load all the sounds needed
    public Sound jumpSound;
    public Sound buttonClicked;
    public Music backgroundMusic;

    GameState gameState;

    //On Pause stuff
    public static Vector2 fish_pause_pos;

    public MainMenuScreen(FishyDash game) {
        this.game = game;
        gameState = GameState.READY;

        System.out.println("first");
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("second");
        //Initialize all the sounds
        jumpSound = Assets.manager.get(Assets.jumpSound, Sound.class);
        buttonClicked = Assets.manager.get(Assets.buttonClicked, Sound.class);
        backgroundMusic = Assets.manager.get(Assets.backgroundMusic, Music.class);
        backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);
        backgroundMusic.setVolume(.5f);
        backgroundMusic.play();

        //Initialize the textures needed in the MainMenuScreen class
        background = Assets.manager.get(Assets.background, Texture.class);
        floor = Assets.manager.get(Assets.floor, Texture.class);
        foreground = Assets.manager.get(Assets.foreground, Texture.class);

        fishy = new Fish();
        fishy.setPos(80, foreground.getHeight() + FOREGROUND_Y_OFFSET - 150);
        fishy.setMOVEMENT_X(200);
        fishy.setGRAVITY(-40);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        cam.setToOrtho(false, background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());

        foregroundPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
        foregroundPos2 = new Vector2(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) + foreground.getWidth(), 0);

        floorPos1 = new Vector2(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2), 0);
        floorPos2 = new Vector2(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) + floor.getWidth(), 0);

        createTable();

//        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
//        game.getAdsController().showBannerAd();
    }

    public void createTable() {
        gamePort = new StretchViewport(FishyDash.V_WIDTH, FishyDash.V_HEIGHT, cam);
        stage = new Stage(gamePort, game.batch);
        stage.getViewport().setCamera(cam);

        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        buttonTable = new Table();
        buttonTable.setFillParent(true);
        buttonTable.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        game_title = new Image(new Texture("game_title.png"));
        font = Assets.manager.get(Assets.font, BitmapFont.class);
        buttonAtlas = Assets.manager.get(Assets.buttonAtlas, TextureAtlas.class);
        skin = new Skin(buttonAtlas);

        //Creating the TextStyle for the playButton
        TextButton.TextButtonStyle playButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        playButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button_up");
        playButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button_down");
        playButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        playButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        playButtonStyle.font = font;

        //Creating the TextStyle for the rateButton
        TextButton.TextButtonStyle rateButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        rateButtonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("button_up");
        rateButtonStyle.down = skin.getDrawable("button_down");
        rateButtonStyle.pressedOffsetX = 1;
        rateButtonStyle.pressedOffsetY = -1;
        rateButtonStyle.font = font;

        //Setting the style and text for the playButton
        buttonPlay = new TextButton("PlAY", playButtonStyle);
        buttonPlay.pad(10);

        //Setting the style and text for the rateButton
        buttonRate = new TextButton("RATE", rateButtonStyle);
        buttonRate.pad(10);

        table.top();
        table.add(game_title).padTop(175).expandX();

        buttonTable.bottom().padBottom(200);
        buttonTable.add(buttonPlay).expandX().padLeft(30);
        buttonTable.add(buttonRate).expandX().padRight(30);

//        table.debug();
        stage.addActor(table);
        stage.addActor(buttonTable);

        buttonPlay.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                buttonClicked.play();
                dispose();
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
        });

        buttonRate.addListener(new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                buttonClicked.play();
                System.out.println("Nothing happens Yet");
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateWorld(float delta) {

        switch (gameState) {
            case READY:

                fishy.update(delta);

                if (fishy.getPosition().y < foreground.getHeight() + FOREGROUND_Y_OFFSET - 35) {
                    fishy.setMOVEMENT_X(100);
                }

                if (fishy.getPosition().y < floor.getHeight() + FLOOR_Y_OFFSET + 150) {
                    fishy.setMOVEMENT_X(100);
                    fishy.normalJump();
                    jumpSound.stop();
                }

                updateForeground();
                updateFloor();

                cam.position.x = fishy.getPosition().x + (cam.viewportWidth / 2) - 80;
                cam.update();

                table.setPosition(cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, 0);
                buttonTable.setPosition(cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, 0);

                Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
                break;

            case PAUSED:
                gameState = GameState.READY;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void drawWorld() {
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        switch (gameState) {

            case READY:
                game.batch.begin();

                game.batch.draw(background, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, 0);

                game.batch.draw(foreground, foregroundPos1.x, foregroundPos1.y + FOREGROUND_Y_OFFSET);
                game.batch.draw(foreground, foregroundPos2.x, foregroundPos2.y + FOREGROUND_Y_OFFSET);

                game.batch.draw(floor, floorPos1.x, floorPos1.y + FLOOR_Y_OFFSET);
                game.batch.draw(floor, floorPos2.x, floorPos2.y + FLOOR_Y_OFFSET);

                game.batch.draw(fishy.getAnimation().getKeyFrame(fishy.timePassed, true),
                        fishy.getPosition().x, fishy.getPosition().y);

                game.batch.end();

                stage.act();
                stage.draw();
                break;

            case PAUSED:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        updateWorld(delta);
        drawWorld();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        System.out.println("Main Menu Dispose Called");

        fishy.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }

    public void updateForeground() {
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > foregroundPos1.x + foreground.getWidth())
            foregroundPos1.add(foreground.getWidth() * 2, 0);
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > foregroundPos2.x + foreground.getWidth())
            foregroundPos2.add(foreground.getWidth() * 2, 0);
    }

    public void updateFloor() {
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > floorPos1.x + floor.getWidth())
            floorPos1.add(floor.getWidth() * 2, 0);
        if(cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth / 2) > floorPos2.x + floor.getWidth())
            floorPos2.add(floor.getWidth() * 2, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        System.out.println("pause");
        gameState = GameState.PAUSED;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        System.out.println("resume");
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        System.out.println("hide");
    }

    public enum GameState {
        READY, PAUSED;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

from what i understand changing the asset manager to a what i have below should work, however when I do this change the I cant use manager anymore, it becomes highlighted in red and gives me the error Non-Static Field manager cannot be referenced from a non static content?

```
AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static final String font = "fonts/mario.fnt";

    public static final String jumpSound = "sounds/jumpSound.wav";
    public static final String buttonClicked = "sounds/buttonClicked.wav";
    public static final String passSound = "sounds/passSound.wav";
    public static final String gameOver = "sounds/gameOver.mp3";
    public static final String backgroundMusic = "sounds/backgroundMusic.wav";

    public static final String background = "background.png";
    public static final String floor = "floor.png";
    public static final String foreground = "foreground.png";

    public static final String fishAtlas = "sprite_animations/fishy_sprite_ani.atlas";
    public static final String buttonAtlas = "ui/buttons.atlas";


    public Assets() {
    }

    public static void load() {
        manager.load(font, BitmapFont.class);

        manager.load(jumpSound, Sound.class);
        manager.load(buttonClicked, Sound.class);
        manager.load(passSound, Music.class);
        manager.load(gameOver, Music.class);
        manager.load(backgroundMusic, Music.class);

        manager.load(background, Texture.class);
        manager.load(floor, Texture.class);
        manager.load(foreground, Texture.class);

        manager.load(fishAtlas, TextureAtlas.class);
        manager.load(buttonAtlas, TextureAtlas.class);

    }
```

Comment: This has been asked many times before. Don't make static references to AssetManagers or Textures. Exiting an Android Activity does not exit the entire application, so static references will remain.

Comment: @ Tenfour04 I added my Assets code and i was hoping you could enlighten me on this. I read in the wiki that this is the correct way to do things however I cant seem to use manager.load()?

Comment: Can you link where in the wiki it says to do that? You can technically have a static reference to assets, but you need to know exactly what you're doing if you do, and it's error prone. Beginners keep making mistakes with this, so the wiki should be cleaned up.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager) im still trying to figure this out but im not sure what to do. So right now in my dispose method of my asset class i added manager = null, after disposing of the manager. I tried using Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true) and then disposing of the assest in there but it would just load a black screen

Comment: That links says: **Caution** and proceeds to tell you why you *should not* use the `static` keyword with assets.

Comment: @EdwardLim The reason `load` is not functioning anymore is because you are referencing a `none static field inside a static method`. A static method belongs to the class so can be invoked without creating an object. It would be strange if it would have access to the non static AssetManager that only gets created when making an Object of that class.

Comment: @EdwardLim If you want to create a none static `AssetManager` you have to make the Load method none static or have it receive a AssetManager as a overload. But, I have been using static AssetManagers for a long time without problems. I use it with `AssetDescriptors` http://pastebin.com/hWDznS8n, you could try if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid static asset references. When an Android Activity is backed out of, the Application stays alive, so statically referenced objects stay alive as well until the next time you launch your game (a new Activity instance) from the launcher.

You can technically have a static reference to assets, but you need to know exactly what you're doing if you do, and it's error prone.  (You would have to be absolutely sure everything is disposed of when the Activity closes, clear your static references to null, and also ensure that you load new instances when the game starts up again.) It is safest to avoid any static reference to anything that implements `Disposable`.

You need to read up on Java's class objects (not classes, not objects, but "class objects") so you'll understand what's going on here. A `static` method cannot operate on a non-`static` member variable, so you also need to remove the `static` key word from your `load` method.

And then to access your asset manager, you need to create an instance of your Assets class and access it through a standard member variable:

```
public class FishyDash extends Game {

    Assets assets;

    public void create(){
        assets = new Assets();
        assets.load();
        //....
    }

}

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{

    //...

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("second");

        jumpSound = game.assets.manager.get(Assets.jumpSound, Sound.class);
        //...
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: OMG! I love you so much right now, this was absolutely the kind of information I need, sorry I didnt quite understand your previous comments.. But I see know my mistakes, I completely overlooked that my load method was static I dont know how but I did. I just didnt put two and two together. But this right here is the solution! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

It is problem with **static instances of objects existing in the background** even if you close the app.

Make sure that you are disposing, nulling and creating as new when app open all instances of assets managers.

Use

```
AssetManager manager;

...

manager.clear();
```

also **dispose** skin if you use some and set **null** to your handlers if you use some as singletones for example

Comment: i dont believe im using any static instance variables?

Comment: then check your asset managers or other objects you should dispose - the list is here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management

Comment: ok so i was using this public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(); but now i changed it to this AssetManager manager = new AssetManager(); however the problem is that it gives me the error non static field 'manager' cannot be referenced from a static context. My manger is now red in color, any solutions to this?

Comment: you don't need to make **static** field non static! If you use it as static keep it - just make sure that on dispose method you are disposing it and setting the reference to null - that's all

Answer (score 0):

Here's the more dangerous answer. I only recommend doing this if you fully understand the Android lifecycle, the Libgdx lifecycle, and Java's class objects.

You can keep your static asset references, but you must ensure they are disposed of when the game closes.

```
public class Assets {

    //Safer to keep this private and use below public method for access
    private static AssetManager manager; //do not instantiate here

    public static AssetManager manager(){
        if (manager == null) load();
        return manager;
    }

    public static void load (){
        if (manager == null) manager = new AssetManager();

        //your existing load code
    }

    public static void dispose() {
        if (manager != null){
            manager.dispose();
            manager = null;
       }
    }

}

public class FishyDash extends Game {

    //...

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        Assets.dispose();
    }
}

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{

    //...

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("second");

        //NOTE THE PARENTHESES AFTER manager below
        jumpSound = Assets.manager().get(Assets.jumpSound, Sound.class);
        //...
    }

    //...

}
```